# MySql comparing two list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 65 tables, and 1 master list. Each item in the master list has an email address and a table name (one of the 65 tables names) but my problem is the table names are cut off.

so I would get items like 'Ancaster', 'Ancaster-', 'Ancaster-Glen', 'Ancaster-Glen-Phase-2'

Each item in the 65 tables has an email address.

What I am trying to do is compare the email address in the master list to each of the tables to get a final list (65 list) I understand I would have to do this 65 times.

Would this query give me what I need?

`SELECT Ancaster-glen.* FROM Ancaster-glen INNER JOIN Master-Table on Master-Table.emailaddress = Ancaster-glen.emailaddress WHERE tablename like 'Ancaster%'`

I tried it out, it seems okay, I would just want to confirm. Or if anybody has another suggestion to get what I am trying accomplish, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to union select all data together.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( ... your unions ...) as bigunion
WHERE condition = xyz
```

Comment: I dont think a union is what I want....I am looking to do this 65 times to give me 65 results, that I can export to csv.